# How to get SceneKit node placed over detected image to stay put as camera moves?

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I'm very new to ARKit, and have built a small app based on Apple's "Detecting Images in an AR Experience" sample app. The sample app places a plane over the detected image; my app places an SCNBox at the center of it instead.

If the detected image is displayed on my monitor, I can move the phone all around and the box will stay fixed at the center of the image, which is what I want. If, however, the image is displayed on another iPhone, the box will move around as I move the phone running my app. Possibly due to the smaller screen size?

Here is my implementation of the didAdd delegate method:

```
  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    updateQueue.async {
      let cube = self.createCubeNode() // returns an SCNNode with SCNBox geometry
      let position = SCNVector3(x: imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.x,
                                y: imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.y,
                                z: imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)
      cube.worldPosition = position

      self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cube)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Instead of positioning and adding my cube node in didAdd, returning the node from nodeFor and letting the system place it completely fixes the problem.  So I have removed the above code and replaced it with:

```
  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    // make sure this is an image anchor, otherwise bail out
    guard let _ = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return nil }

    return self.createCubeNode() // returns an SCNNode with SCNBox geometry
  }
```

I got this idea from a Hacking With Swift article:  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arkit/how-to-detect-images-using-arimagetrackingconfiguration